# Error while building Unity 8

Tags: 12.04, unity, apt, updates, ppa

I was following the steps given on this [page](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/) to build Unity 8. When i run the command `./build -s`, it works fine, adds the PPAs required and then it runs the `apt-get` command, and therein lies the error. I get the following error-

> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/desktop-deps/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

and

> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/desktop-deps/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

And so the, `./build -s` command is not executed properly, how can this be solved? My system is on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step of the instructions you're following says "First make sure you’re desktop working environment is at least 13.10 / saucy".

[The PPA that you are trying to add](https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/desktop-deps) currently only contains packages for Saucy, which accounts for the error you received.  While you could potentially rebuild those packages for 12.04, there are almost certainly other dependencies that are not satisfied by what is in that version.

It is possible that someone will backport Unity 8 to that version in the future, but while it is under heavy development, your best bet is to use what the developers are working with.

Comment: is there any way Unity 8 can be run on 12.04?

Comment: I don't think there is at present.  If you can not upgrade the system, one option would be to install 13.10 in a VM (e.g. using VirtualBox) and test things from there.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! i think i'll test things out in VM then.